# arangodb traverse tree including edges

Tags: arangodb

Using 'GRAPH_TRAVERSAL_TREE' in my AQL only returns the vertices, is there away of returning the edge documents together with the vertices. Example:

```
FOR item in GRAPH_TRAVERSAL_TREE('graph','_id','outbound','items')
  Return item
```

Returns something like:

```
[
  {vertex},
  items:[
   {vertex, items:[]},
   {vertex, items:[]},
  ]
]
```

I would like the edge information to be included in the result as below

```
[
  {vertex},
  items:[
   {edge:{edge}, vertex:{vertex}, items:[]},
   {edge:{edge}, vertex:{vertex}, items:[]},
  ]
]
```

Using AQL without graph functions I have this:

```
for item in items filter item._id == 'items/212612934312'
  return {'head': item, 'items': [(
    for edge in itemEdges filter edge._from == item._id
      for vertex in items filter vertex._id == edge._to
        return {'edge': edge, 'vertex': vertex}
)]}
```

But I am sure there should be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported , if you need that you have to raise a change request. 
An alternative might be to use GRAPH_SHORTEST_PATH but i am not 100% if this fits for your use case:

GRAPH_SHORTEST_PATH("graph", '_id', {}, {direction : "outbound"})

Comment: @z999 where you able to use GRAPH_SHORTEST_PATH successfully?

Comment: I will need to spent more time with GRAPH_SHORTEST_PATH to see how I can format the result in the tree structure. I am also looking at using GRAPH_NEIGHBORS.